# How to allow specific ip access in nginx

Tags: nginx

I just want to restrict access my website so i used nginx **allow** and **deny** but this cause deny all ips including allowed ip

my nginx config

```
upstream myapp {
  server 127.0.0.1:xxxx;
}

server {
  listen port_number;
  server_name my_server_ip;
  charset utf-8;
  client_max_body_size 75M;

  location / {
    allow ip_allowed;
    deny all;
    uwsgi_pass myapp;
    include /etc/nginx/uwsgi_params;
  }
}
```

please help me

Comment: Are you sure that your request comes from `ip_allowed`?

Comment: yes , i am using django , uwsgi and nginx

Comment: Check access log. There should be remote ip